# Добавление функций в Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Доброго времени суток.

Отступление:

Есть задание: организовать отображение user'ов на карте (google.maps | yandex.maps | чего-либо еще).
Имеется база данных с таблицей User. В ней нас интересует два поля: прошлый ip входа и текущий. Необходимо, повторюсь, отобразить на карте в виде меток данных пользователей.

Проблема заключается с дополнением функций device (уже имеющихся или же написания дополнительной своей функции). Последнее, кстати, почему-то плодов никаких не принесло, может сделал что не так.

В общем, буду рад помощи в этом направлении.

**Интересующие вопросы:**

1. *(при попытке текущей реализации)* Как сделать функцию, которая будет выполняться сразу после входа user'а на сайт, для того, чтобы в добавленные поля в таблице внести изменения - широту и долготу исходя из их ip *(использую стотонную API'шку)*
2. *(или второй вариант)* - у админа на страничке, когда он ее посещает *(панель управления)* чтобы все ip-адреса user'ов передавались в некий массив, и исходя из него дописывались в запрос к сторонней API'шке. *(с самой страницей и отображением на ней всё получилось, но есть загвоздка: **в каком виде хранить данные типа ip-адреса**, чтобы ими хоть как-то можно было работать)*

Рад буду, если будут какие-нибудь реальные примеры кода.

Вот код, контроллера, который я пытался реализовать (для первого метода). И данный код не выполняется (т.е. в терминале не появляется данная пробная запись)

```
class CustomSessionsController < Device::SessionsController
    before_filter :before_login, only [:update, :new, :create]
    after_filter :after_login, only [:update, :new, :create]#, only => :update

    public

    def before_login

    end

    def after_login
        puts "\n\n‿︵‿ヽ(°□° )ノ︵‿︵Получилось!‿︵‿ヽ(°□° )ノ︵‿︵\n"
    end
end
```

для вызова данного контроллера в `rotes.rb` была дописана строка: `devise_for :controllers => {:sessions => "custom_sessions"}`.

Файл `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'admin/index'
  get 'users/index'
  resources :direction_statuses
  resources :response_measures
  resources :violations
  resources :reasons
  scope '(:locale)', locale: /en|ru/ do
    get 'dashboard/report'

    devise_for :users,  skip: [:sessions]
    unauthenticated do
      as :user do
        get '', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
        post '', to: 'devise/sessions#create', as: :user_session
      end
    end

    devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "custom_sessions"}

    authenticated do
      as :user do
        delete '', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
      end
    end

    authenticate :user, ->(u) { u.is_admin == true } do
      resources :checks
      resources :people
      resources :organizations
      resources :reports
      resources :inspectors
      resources :categories
      resources :users
      resource  :admin
    end

    authenticate :user, ->(u) { u.is_admin == false } do
      resources :checks
      resources :people
      resources :organizations
      resources :reports
      resources :inspectors
      resources :categories
    end

    resources :checks, only: %i[index show]
    resources :people, only: %i[index show]
    get 'dashboard/index'
    get 'dashboard/info'

    root 'dashboard#index'
    resources :organizations, only: %i[index show]
    resources :reports, only: %i[index show]
    resources :inspectors, only: %i[index show]
  end
end
```

При реализации второго же метода была проблема с занесением в какую-нибудь переменную (т.к. страничная верстка - js) ip-адреса пользователя/пользователей.

Comment: Ответы. 1. Создаёте свой SessionsController и в create после super вызываете ваш метод, который будет сохранять широту и долготу исходя из ip. 2. Тот же самый метод вызываете в нужном экшне админского контроллера, просто передаёте в него весь массив айпишников. Если у вас постгрес, то для айпишников есть тип `inet`. Посмотрите, какой тип у столбца `current_sign_in_ip` в модели пользователя, Devise уже подумал за вас. Была бы рада ответить с примерами кода, но для этого надо посмотреть на ваш код сначала.

Comment: Василиса, какой именно документ желательно Вам предоставить? И можно чуть по-подробнее относительно создания нового контроллера. Потому что последнее у меня не дало никаких результатов.

Comment: Василиса, и еще, насчет типа inet я понимал и видел ни раз) Вопрос был мною не дописан, получается, но, я хотел именно прописать выполнение данного сценария (2) на странице отображающейся именно администратору, т.е. я описывал действия с использованием JS.

Comment: Вот именно ваши попытки создания контроллера неплохо бы и показать, тогда есть шанс, что вам расскажут, почему не получилось. Иначе это выглядит так - я задал вопрос, на пальцах объяснил, что у меня в проекте есть, а в ответ хочу видеть код. Увы, это так не работает.

Comment: В вашем вопросе ни слова про JS. У вас эта самая карта с пользователями на той самой страничке админа? Тогда надо понимать, в каком формате вам надо передать айпишники

Comment: Владимир, пожалуйста, обновите ваш вопрос и добавьте в него код. Вы же видите, что в комментах он совершенно не читаем. И да, что именно в нём не работает? Выдаёт ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я всё правильно помню, то фильтры просто так в девайсовских контроллерах работать не будут. Просто вызовите нужный вам метод после super.

```
class CustomSessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super 
    puts "\n\n‿︵‿ヽ(°□° )ノ︵‿︵Получилось!‿︵‿ヽ(°□° )ノ︵‿︵\n"
  end
end
```

И да, я надеюсь `devise_for :controllers => {:sessions => "custom_sessions"}` - это просто опечатка, и там всё же `devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "custom_sessions"}.`

Проблему во втором сценарии можно решить, если AJAX запрос делать не напрямую в API, а в свой же рельсовый экшн контроллера, который спокойно соберёт все айпишники, отправит их в API, получит результат, обработает его и вернёт вам на фронт.

UPD:

Давайте посмотрим на эту часть:

```
devise_for :users,  skip: [:sessions]
unauthenticated do
  as :user do
    get '', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
    post '', to: 'devise/sessions#create', as: :user_session
  end
end

devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "custom_sessions"}

authenticated do
  as :user do
    delete '', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  end
end
```

Здесь вы дважды вызываете `devise_for :users` и таким образом дублируете все роуты. Должно быть:

```
devise_for :users,  skip: [:sessions]
unauthenticated do
  as :user do
    get '', to: 'custom_sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
    post '', to: 'custom_sessions#create', as: :user_session
  end
end

authenticated do
  as :user do
    delete '', to: 'custom_sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  end
end
```

Дальше. Зачем вы дублируете роуты с результатами аутентификации `u.is_admin == true/false`? Можно проще

```
authenticated do
  resources :checks
  resources :people
  resources :organizations
  resources :reports
  resources :inspectors
  resources :categories
end

authenticate :user, ->(u) { u.is_admin == true } do
  resources :users
  resource  :admin
end
```

Полезно периодически вызывать в терминале `rake routes` и проверять, не дублируется ли что-то.

Comment: При попытке развернуть сервер с данным кодом у меня вывалилось большое количество ошибок:
Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

Comment: Не могли бы Вы более подробно объяснить, в какую область `routes.rb` желательно встраивать своего контроллера.

Comment: А давайте вы лучше выложите свой routes.rb и мы разберёмся, что там не так

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, вот эта вся кастомизация sessions_contoller'a `get '', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session` для того, чтобы изменить url?

Comment: @ВладимирНикель, кстати, когда обновляете вопрос, пингуйте попросившего об этом в комментах, само по себе обновление мне не видно :(

Comment: @ВладимирНикель, обновила ответ, посмотрите

Comment: насчет кастомизации - мне необходимо, чтобы после авторизации пользователя происходил вызов моей дополнительной функции, которая просто будет обращаться к сторонней API и получать из ip-адреса широту и долготу, полученные данные будут вноситься в базу данных. И всё. Пока что я видел только такое решение моего задания. Если есть более оптимальные, а не костыльные идеи, как у меня сейчас - я рад буду перенять знания.